# Can I share typedefs (Google Closure) across source files?

Tags: google-closure

If I define a typedef in one file, for example:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   prop1: string,
 *   prop2: number
 * }}
 */
myClass.typedef;
```

Can I share it across files? I don't want to have to declare the same typedef in every file.

I tried to do `goog.provide('myClass.typedef');` in the file which defines it and `goog.require('myClass.typedef');` in the other file which needs to use it. But I get an error "goog.require could not find myClass.typedef". I believe the provide/require is working in general as `goog.provide('myClass');` and `goog.require('myClass');` is working for the same two files.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, is the error exactly "goog.require could not find my.typedef" and not using "myClass.typedef" or is that abbreviated?

Comment: Typo on my part. The error says "myClass.typeDef". Fixed in the original.

Answer (score 0):

yes, typedefs are shareable, but you will need something else in the file which is included in and needed by the deps system.
Before you use typedefs i would recommend you read this:
http://closuretools.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/type-checking-tips.html

Comment: I believe I'm already doing this. As mentioned in my post, goog.provide('myClass') and goog.require('myClass') is working just fine, it's just the typeDef that generates the error.

Comment: we share typedefs across the board sans any issues. Did you add a goog.provide for the typedef? It is in anycase recommended not to use typedefs.

Answer (score 0):

you can only goog.require things that have been goog.provide-ed.

Either goog.require the class with the type set on it, or create another class such as MyClassTypes and set the type on it 
e.g.
    goog.provide('MyClass');

```
MyClass = function () {};

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   prop1: string,
 *   prop2: number
 * }}
 */
MyClass.type1;
```

or

```
goog.provide('MyClassTypes');

MyClassTypes = function () {};

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   prop1: string,
 *   prop2: number
 * }}
 */
MyClassTypes.type1;
```

and in the file which needs the typedef...

```
goog.require('MyClass');
```

or

```
goog.require('MyClassTypes');
```